# How do I sort records in a text file and how to print other txt file using Java?

Tags: java, file, sorting, text-files

Some amendments to the data in the text file. I have tried the suggested code but I'm not successfully writing it again in the txt file with this format. I've tried the collection. sort but it writes the data in long lines.

My txt file contains these data:

PID1,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID2,WILLIAMS^RORY,M,19881102
PID3,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID4,POND^AMY,F,20010911

How can I sort those data in ascending order and store them again in a txt file after sorting?

0:
PID1,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID3,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID4,POND^AMY,F,20010911
1:
PID2,WILLIAMS^RORY,M,19881102

Comment: output text file's containing long lines means your output method calls are not adding newlines appropriately, I suppose. Show your "reproducible example" here to describe your "real" problem.

Comment: Please share your attempt. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72314505/edit) the question and provide your existing code as a text with the appropriate formatting applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily sort records in a text file and export the result to another txt file with [esProc SPL](https://github.com/SPLWare/esProc)(a java based open-source scripting language for data processing):

IIUC,the data.txt like this:

```
PID1,POND^AMY,F,19890224 PID2,WILLIAMS^RORY,M,19881102 PID3,POND^AMY,F,19890224 PID4,POND^AMY,F,20010911
```

and you wanna sort records by the 2nd field(POND^AMY,WILLIAMS^RORY) and the result.txt like this:

```
0: PID1,POND^AMY,F,19890224 PID3,POND^AMY,F,19890224 PID4,POND^AMY,F,20010911 1: PID2,WILLIAMS^RORY,M,19881102
```

SPL code:

```
=file("result.txt").write(file("data.txt").read().split(" ").group(~.split@c()(2)).((#-1)/": "/~.concat(" ")).concat(" "))
```

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as sort.splx and invoke it in a Java application as you call a stored procedure:

```
...
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call sort.splx()");
st.execute();
...
```

with

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.scudata.esproc/esproc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.scudata.esproc</groupId>
    <artifactId>esproc</artifactId>
    <version>20220402</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also execute the SPL code within a Java program as we execute a SQL statement:

```
...
st = con.prepareStatement("==file(\"result.txt\").export@c(file(\"data.txt\").import@c().sort(_2))");
st.execute();
...
```

Or if your txt actually is a csv format like this:

```
PID1,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID2,WILLIAMS^RORY,M,19881102
PID3,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID4,POND^AMY,F,20010911
```

and you wanna get the result.txt like this:

```
PID1,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID3,POND^AMY,F,19890224
PID4,POND^AMY,F,20010911
PID2,WILLIAMS^RORY,M,19881102
```

use this SPL code:

```
=file("result.txt").export@c(file("data.txt").import@c().sort(_2))
```